# Network Error (tcp_error) A communication error occurred: ""

Tags: php, apache, http, ubuntu, zend-framework2

Last days, I deployed a PHP app(ZF2) on a EC2 instance(Ubuntu Server 12.04).

I installed classic packages for a LAMP environment.

I defined my vhost then I test my website.

The website worked fine and sometimes I have the error :

**Network Error (tcp_error)  A communication error occurred: ""**

I have no error. I checked Apache logs, PHP logs, etc but I found nothing why I have this error something.

When I reload the page, the page works again...

I would like to know if someone already got this case and can give me a way for resolve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: If someone has the same case, you can look in your apache2.conf. 

I defined KeepAlive = Off and it's working now.

I don't find why I have errors with the default config.

Comment: Micro instance are not so stable. This link can help you :http://imperialwicket.com/tuning-apache-for-a-low-memory-server-like-aws-micro-ec2-instances