# Laravel, Dropzone, and S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I have dropzone configured with Laravel and S3, for small files everything works smoothly. I can see files uploaded.

I am trying to upload 2.5MB file using the same approach but nothing works I always get

```
`Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Can't send more" The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.`
```

I changed PHP settings to increase `upload size` and `max_post_size`, yet nothing worked

what could be the issue?

The code in the controller below

```
  $video = $request->file('file');
    if($video !==null) {
        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $stamp = Carbon::now();
        $email = $request->header('email');
        $videoFileName = $email . $stamp->toDateTimeString() . '.' . $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filePath = 'videos/' . $videoFileName;
        $s3->put($filePath, fopen($video, 'r+'), 'public');
        Mail::queue('emails.videoUploaded', ['email' => $email], function ($message) use($email) {
            $message->from('mohammad@findearlyadopters.com', 'Mohammad Abu Musa');
            $message->to($email);
            $message->subject('Video Uploaded - FindEarlyAdopters.com');
        });

        Mail::queue('emails.uploadedVideoNotification', ['email' => $email , 'videoLocation'=>$s3->url($filePath)], function ($message) use ($email) {
            $message->from('videos@findearlyadopters.com', 'Mohammad Abu Musa');
            $message->to("mohammad@findearlyadopters.com");
            $message->subject('New Video Uploaded - FindEarlyAdopters.com');
        });

        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => true,
        ));
    }
```

DropZone.js code is below

```
$("#videoUploader").dropzone({
        url: "{{route('postTestVideo')}}",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            'email':getParameterByName('email')
        },
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                if(response.success == true)
                    window.location="{{route('yourTests',array('thank-you'=>true))}}";
                else
                    $('#error').show();
            })
        }
    });
```

I am using dokku to deploy the code here is what I have in the config now

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C httpd.inc.conf -i php.ini public/`

httpd.inc.conf

```
`Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 50
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers          3
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers       5
    MaxClients            10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

and this is what I have in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 150M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_execution_time = 86400
max_file_uploads = 40
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125245/network-error-tcp-error-a-communication-error-occurred

Comment: http://imperialwicket.com/tuning-apache-for-a-low-memory-server-like-aws-micro-ec2-instances/

Comment: I read this article, I thought it would solve the issue but did not work unfortunately

Comment: I'll try to research a little more tomorrow. I still think this is aws issue not laravel or framework.

Comment: Thanks, I will check aws more now. I will post the solution once I find it

Comment: @manshu I checked the $request->all() when I upload a video file it return empty array but when when I upload a text file it sends all the information. could this help

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 50
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers          3
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers       5
    MaxClients            10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>

# if you are using workers, update the IfModule worker.c section similarly.
/etc/php.ini

memory_limit = 100M
```

Comment: Have you tried them before? I have no clue what these commands do

Comment: Run these on your terminal, they will change the block size of your memory

Comment: for small files it works, I tried to upload a 3 MB file it did not work

Comment: I just edited the question, you can find the code for both client and server side

Comment: Code looks fine, can you check amazon console to see if there is an option for limit ?

Comment: Can not find an limitation, the file I am trying to send is very 3 MB I do not think there will be limitation for that, right?

Comment: Did not work out, I tried this code in apache config. same issue